# Serving Font Files from a Heroku Cedar Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, truetype

I'm working on a webpage for my wedding and I am trying to customize the font on the heading. When I try to serve a `.tff` file from my `/public/fonts` folder, I get the following error in Chrome:

```
Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.
```

The stylesheet uses the following lines:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: elegant;
    src: url(/fonts/adine-kirnberg-script.ttf);
}
header {
    font-size: 64px;
    font-family: elegant;
}
```

I can download the font file at `/fonts/adine-kirnberg-script.ttf` so I know it's not that the file isn't being served, but apparently the MIME type is causing the bug.

I'm going crazy trying to figure out how to solve the problem, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try serving the font with the `application/x-font-ttf` or `font/ttf` mime type.

In one of your app's initializers configure the mime type like this:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/x-font-ttf", :ttf
```